# RDLC Print PageHeader Only on First Page

Tags: rdlc

Is there a way to show the report header only on the first page? Just as expected the PageHeader.PrintOnFirstPage only shows or hides the header for the first page only. The customer wants the header to show up only on the first page, kinda like a title in a document. I looked at [MS-RDL.pdf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240083.aspx) and [RDL200501](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition/) with no luck. My reports are RDLC not RDL but it should not matter. If there is no straightforward solution I will look into writing custom code to supress the header on pages > 1.

Comment: I wish i could find a solid answer for this

Answer (score 5):

If you need the header to be on the first page only, why struggle to put it inside the `PageHeader` anyway?

Instead, remove the `PageHeader` altogether and design whatever you want as the 'header' directly at the top most body.

Just my two cents.